# When I compile my project I get error: Unable to find a javac compiler

Tags: java, android, cocos2d-android

I am trying create a simple game in cocos2d-x, but when I compile my project I get the following error.

> BUILD FAILED D:\Android\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:597: The following
>   error occurred while executing this line:
>   D:\Android\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:716: The following error occurred
>   while executing this line: D:\Android\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:730:
>   Unable to find a javac compiler; com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on
>   the classpath. Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK. It is
>   currently set to "D:\JAVA"
>
> Total time: 2 seconds Error running command, return code: 1.
>   D:\cocos2d-x\GAME>

Comment: Please post your code =)

Answer (score 1):

You should post more details, but a first attempt by reading your post would be that you have not set up your Java correctly. Your JAVA_HOME points to "D:\JAVA". Are you sure that you have a valid java installation/runtime (jdk) there? Inside this folder there should be a "bin" folder containing `java` and `javac` commands.